# Radio button (as button) bleeding into frame

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some radio buttons that are being rendered as actual buttons and the selected one bleeds into the modal-footer. I am using bootstrap. The code is:

```
<td>
    <div class="btn-group radio-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input id="ID1" name="Name1" type="radio" value="True">
            A
        </label>
        <label class="active btn btn-default">
            <input checked="checked" id="ID1" name="Name1" type="radio" value="False">
            B
        </label>
    </div>
</td>
```

And here is a picture of what's happening.
[image]
I know that I'm not including all of the CSS and Modal code, but I'm hoping someone can at least point to a direction for research.

Thanks!

Comment: bootstrap V3 ?..

Comment: Can you please provide the footer code you are using as well?

Comment: it's a z-index issue, the active has a `z-index: 2;` so am pretty sure it's bigger than the other modal

Comment: It does indeed look like the z-index. I'll play around and reply definitely when I'm sure. Thanks!